# How to compile multiple cpp files and run executable in an external terminal window in vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, terminal, g++

Currently, I am using a vs code extension "C/C++ Compile Run" to compile and run single cpp files. For multiple files, I am using the extension "C/C++ Project Generator" which creates a project folder, including a makefile that helps build everything together. However, when I use the command `make run` it runs the executable in vscode's integrated terminal, unlike the first extension which gives the option to run the executable in an external terminal window.

Are there any ways to compile multiple files (.cpp and .h) and run the executable in an external terminal window in vscode? Moreso with the click of a single button?

Comment: You can take my word for it, and/or discover it on your own. Use cmake with vscode. With the proper extensions installed its the cats whiskers. Just saying.

Comment: You could set up the build task so that it compiles all the files in your workspace, and then run the program from an external terminal window. Here's a link that can help you get started with [VS Code tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks).